# Inline javascript function call from variable

Tags: javascript, function, null, undefined, inline

I want to call a function inline from a variable, but respecting the case, when the variable is null / undefined or not a function.

```
var f;
if(typeof(f) == 'function') {
    f(); // don't get executed
}
f(); // this is of course not working, but it is executing

var fn = function() { console.warn('fn'); }
fn(); // working because fn is a function
```

Basically I want the if statement, with checking whether the variable is a function or not in one line.

I saw this and thought there has to something for undefined / non functions:

```
var screenSize = screen.width || 1024;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a logical AND:

```
typeof f === 'function' && f();
```

The second operator is only evaluated if the first one is truish.

Comment: Nice. Is there a way to shorten `typeof f === 'function'`